# Retrieve Rules field using Powershell script in readable format

Tags: powershell-extensions, powershell

We are trying to get report using Powershell to list all sub items under one item and some of it's fields. One field in the item is of Rules field type. We are able to fetch RuleSet XML (<rulesetCustom Rules>) from the field. However we need it in readable format as shown in Content Editor.

Is there any way to fetch it using Powershell?

Thanks,
PC

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer by choosing the checkmark.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to get it working using this approach:

```
$item = Get-Item -Path "master:{F4819743-C9D5-48A4-911B-017F8BA1415C}"
# Change the name 'ShowRule' to whatever your rule field is called
$renderer = New-Object Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Rules.RulesRenderer ($item.ShowRule)

$sw = New-Object System.IO.StringWriter
$renderer.Render($sw)

$records = @()
$records += [PSCustomObject]@{
    "RuleHtml" = $sw.ToString()
}

$records | Show-ListView
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael, This works perfect. Thanks for saving my day.